# read_passphrase being called on SSH key even though SSH key is not protected by password

Tags: ssh

I have a staging server and a production server, and I run identical Bitbucket Pipelines, where I send some commands over SSH. Unfortunately, my pipeline for the production always fails with:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

I've tried *everything*, folder permissions, recreating the keys, nothing works.

Finally with adding `-v` to my `ssh` call, I think I'm a step closer, but still lost.

On my staging server, I see something like this:

```
debug1: Host '$STAGING_SERVER' is known and matches the RSA host key.   
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:4   
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
```

and the rest of the build follows flawlessly.

On my production server, however, I see the following:

```
debug1: Host '$PRODUCTION_SERVER' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
debug1: permanently_drop_suid: 0
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
```

So it would look like the key *is* found on my production server, but for some reason on the production server `read_passphrase` is being called. I've just created a new id_rsa and id_rsa.pub key, with *no* password, so why the heck is my production server trying to call `read_passphrase`? My `ssh_config` and `sshd_config` on both servers are identical - checked via `diff`.

Another way of looking at it is that `ssh_rsa_verify` is called immediately on the staging server, while on the production server `read_passphrase` is called.

Any help here would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me crazy!

Comment: It looks like it's trying to ask something related to the remote server's host key, not your private key. The read_passphrase() function is used for things other than specifically reading a key passphrase.

Comment: Do you mean bitbucket being the remote server, or my remote server? (The production server)

Comment: Whatever server ssh is connecting to. $PRODUCTION_SERVER I suppose.

Comment: Do you mean the various `ssh_host_*` files in `/etc/ssh`? If so, this could be a possible culprit... the ones on the production server are a bit older than those on staging, but not by much, a few weeks difference I guess from when the servers were set up. Would it be a good idea to generate new ones?

Answer (score 0):

**Hallelujah! Solved!**

Hours wasted for the simplest reason...

I noticed in the full output of the `ssh -v` on production that Bitbucket was printing out something like this:

```
debug1: Connecting to $PRODUCTION_SERVER [12.345.567.890] port 22.
```

where as the staging output was:

```
debug1: Connecting to $STAGING_SERVER [$STAGING_SERVER] port 22.
```

Meaning the static IP *was* the exact value of that repository variable. (Bitbucket parses secret logs out, which is why they appear this way).

I realized I had set the repository variable `PRODUCTION_SERVER` incorrectly to the *alias* for the IP address, (i.e. `myserver.com`) when it should be the IP address exactly. Changing that value in my repository variables to the IP address fixed the issue! Apparently, using the alias name isn't a perfect enough match for SSH to be satisfied.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Though I got error ```ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/bin/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.```